# Lattices and noncommutative algebras in noncommutative geometry

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

I am interested in the relation between lattices and noncommutative algebras in the context of noncommutative geometry. In the commutative case, a lattice is a discrete subgroup of a locally compact abelian group, and it can be associated to a commutative C*-algebra via the Pontryagin duality. Is there a similar correspondence in the noncommutative setting? More precisely, can one associate a lattice (or some generalization of it) to a noncommutative C*-algebra or a von Neumann algebra? If so, what are the properties of such a lattice and how does it relate to the spectral or topological aspects of the noncommutative space?

I would appreciate any references or examples on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: There is [some information in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#Dualities_for_non-commutative_topological_groups) although perhaps it's not enough to address the question asked here.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456905/lattices-and-noncommutative-algebras-in-noncommutative-geometry